# React don't rendered the Data that from serve without use reload event

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is an example:
When user logined I send a request to server to get the user information. Then use 'react route history' goto home page, and render the Data from server. But it didn't work, there is no user info rendered in the view. When I reload the page, user info has added to the view. How to deal with it ?  Thank you very much.

Comment: could you please share what you have done so far so that we can look into that

Comment: this is the login handler below, in home page componentDidMount I get the 'token' and 'uid' to request user info and save in 'state'

Comment: How are you passing down the props to home component. You may need to have mapStateToProps there to get the latest values and rerender itself.

Comment: I save them in localStorage

Comment: hard to tell something unless you share all the components with us.

Comment: Well, I will find another way. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

```js
axios.post('/user/login', qs.stringify({
                 uname: uname,
                 pwd: pwd,
                 captcha: captcha,
                 codeid: this.state.codeUUID
             })
         ).then(function (res) {
             let data = res.data.attachment;
             if (res.data.status == 200) {
                 localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                 localStorage.setItem('uid', data.uid);
                    this.context.router.push('/home')
             } else if(res.data.status === 412) {
                    message.error("captcha error")
                    this.getCaptcha();
                    this.refs.captcha.value = ''
             } else {
                    message.error(res.data.message);
                }
         }.bind(this))
```

Comment: Could you please update the question instead since this is misleading here.

Comment: I try to find it, but failed